# constructing CFG

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages

How can I construct a Context-Free Grammer for the language **x^a y^b z^2(a+b)** where  a>=0, b>=0.
Thanks for helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it this way

```
x^a y^b z^2(a+b) = x^a y^b z^2a z^2b = x^a y^b (z^2)^b (z^2)^a
```

Therefore

```
S -> xSzz | S1
S1 -> yS1zz | e
```

Comment: I just tried to undo my upvote for this answer, which I gave when it was only the "Think of it this way" hint, but for some reason I can't. Not only is the answer giving the solution away (for what is most likely a homework problem), it's also not very elegant because the first rule has a redundant `e` clause.

Comment: @larsmans Indeed. I edited the question, you can downvote now.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that for each `x` and for each `y`, you need to generate two `z`'s because of the 2(*a* + *b*). Also, observe that each string can be viewed as an "inside" part of `y`'s and `z`'s, and an "outside" part of `x`'s and `z`'s.

Since for each `y` you need two `z`'s, the inside part can be described by (using capitals to denote non-terminal symbols and `[]` for the empty string):

```
I --> []
I --> y I z z
```

Now write a grammar for the outside part in the same way, but referring to `I` in the base case.

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two cases that you need to treat:

- You can either add an `x` at the beginning of the string, in which case you need to add two `z`’s at the end.
- Or you can add a `y` in the middle, in which case you *also* need to add two `z`’s at the end.

Try reducing either of these descriptions to a simpler grammer (e.g. `a^n b^n`) for which you know the solution.

This hint should be enough to deduce the generative grammer.